# renderInContext throw crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I am rendering images from webview. so renderIncontext method call more than 50 times in for loop. after 20 or 30 times my app crashed because of more memory consuption.

I used this code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake([w floatValue], [h floatValue]));
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(ctx, webview.frame);
[self.webview.layer renderInContext:ctx];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

After 20  times it got crashed. I need its solutions.

Why this occurs? Anyone knows?

Comment: HI,Have you found a solution for this,im also having same problem?If so pls share the solution

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're creating lots of bitmap images in a tight loop.  You need to save off the images you need (probably on disk instead of in memory if you need them all), and allow the images in memory to be autoreleased.  Wrap the body of your loop in an `@autorelease` block like:

```
for (whatever) {
    @autorelease {
        // Work that makes big autoreleased objects.
    }
}
```

This way your memory consumption will not be out of control inside your loop.  Again, you're still going to be allocating tons of memory if you make all these UIImage objects persist.  Save the generated images to a temporary directory (or some other convenient place) on disk and fetch them individually as needed.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that all above code is wrap by @autorelease.  @autorelease{"My COde"}. It helped me but not expected

Comment: Can you post a bit more context?  How are you using the UIImage objects you get from `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`?  Specifically I'm wondering if they're all being retained.

Comment: @autoreleasepool {
        for (int i=0; i<slides; i++) {
            yOrigin = 'something'
            [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scroll(0,%f)",yOrigin]];
            "Above code"
            if (image != nil) {
                add to arr
            }
        }
    }

Comment: OK, first of all putting the `@autorelease` around the `for (foo)` part isn't helping you much because nothing will be autoreleased until your loop ends.  The `@autorelease` should be *inside* the loop.  Secondly, you're putting all those images in an array so they're still going to stick around in memory.  Do you really need all the images in memory at the same time? If you can get away with just showing one (or a few) images at a time, you can save the images to disk as you generate them, and then load just the ones you want to show at any given time to keep your memory footprint reasonable.

Comment: @Helenvoy: In fact, you should save all of the images to storage—either the Caches directory, the Documents directory, or the photos library—unconditionally, and load each one only when it's needed, and be ready to throw any of them that you aren't using away whenever a memory warning comes in.

Comment: I tried both the way. I stored fetched images to document directory. And apply @autorelease inside the loop. But still images can be fetched (with help of renderInCOntext mehod)around of 22 slides. If it goes above it, then app crashed. I also tried to set usleep(10000) at the bottom of loop to pause and help loop to free some memory but still it is not working for more than 22  or 23 slides.

Comment: @AaronGolden : If I misunderstood you somewhere please guide me. I want to do asap. I cant paste whole code here because of limited characters please copy and paste somewhere from below to see whole code.

Comment: for (int i=0; i<slides; i++) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            UIImage* image = nil;
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake([w floatValue], [h floatValue]));
            {yOrigin = 'something'
                [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scroll(0,%f)",yOrigin]];
                webview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [w floatValue], [h floatValue]);
                [webview.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
                image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

Comment: if (image != nil) {
                [add image to document folder]
            }
            usleep(10000);
        }
    }